# Activate Display Mirroring in OS X through Applescript?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, mirroring

Is it possible for someone to AppleScript a way to automate Display Mirroring?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for Applescript so you can do it programmatically, I think https://github.com/fcanas/mirror-displays would be a solution.  The project has two applications, one that is a command line tool to enable/disable/toggle/query mirror state, the other appears to be (I haven't tried it) a more traditional .app that can be added to the Dock and used to toggle mirroring.